# stored procedure using like (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I use the LIKE statement in stored procedures (MySQL) ?

I tried both but I still get errors:

```
..WHERE Des_Articolo LIKE '%nome_art%';

..WHERE Des_Articolo LIKE'%',nome_art,'%';
```

nome_art is declared as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  ric_art (IN nome_art VARCHAR(100) , OUT msg VARCHAR(100))
```

Many thanks Roberto

Answer (score 9):

Use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate strings:

```
WHERE Des_Articolo LIKE CONCAT('%', nome_art, '%');
```

Note: This type of query is slow. If performance is an issue, you may want to consider an alternative approach such as [full-text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot everything goes smoothly.

Comment: Is this not open to SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
..Where Des_Articolo like CONCAT('%',nome_art,'%');
```

Bun Leap_kh